# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bitbucket-pipelines, ng-build, angular-cli-v8

While building ng build I am getting this error in Bitbucket. I am using Firebase as my backend. What am I doing wrong?

> EPERM: operation not permitted, lchown '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/.cache/angular-build-dl/tmp' Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lchown '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/.cache/angular-build-dl/tmp'

[this is my Build Error in Bitbucket Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM5Cp.png)
This is my pipeline

```
'''
 - npm i @types/jquery
      - ng build
      - npm install -g firebase-tools
      - firebase deploy --only hosting --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --project <projrct name> --non-interactive -m "deploying the development version" 

'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the yaml file to give root user assess
something like this.

```
image:
  name: imageName
  run-as-user: 0
```